# Moving to another Activity and waiting for feedback

Tags: android, android-activity

How to do sth like that:
I'm touching the button. Then application is moving me to another activity. Then I'm choosing one of some options and application return to previous Activity and send there information about my choice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for startActivityForResult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use startActivityForResult

First Activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);



 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1){
   String msg = data.getStringExtra("result");
   //Your code...
  }
```

and in the second activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String result = "blablabla";
intent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks, and what should I do if I have more classes to get request? How to separate request form A class and from B class? I have only one onActivityResult function ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of SharedPreference an onResume will work. The first time you start your first Activity there is no SharedPrefrence saved. onResume is called on the first startup, but you have to make some sort of switch that it does nothing if the SharedPreference is null.

Then you go to the second activity. You do something that changes a SharedPreference (example Button). After saveing the Preference you can return to your first Activity.

onResume is called when returning and you can do what you want depending on your choice. Based on your question this will in theory work.